# SharePoint 2013 - How to remove content type from library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, content-type

I accidentally associated a content type to a library, but now realize that it does not need to be a part of this library.  I cannot find any setting to remove this content type (not delete it), from my specific library.

How do we do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should just be a matter of clicking on the Content Type in the library settings and clicking the delete this content type link. It won't delete it from the site collection, but will remove it from the library.

Comment: that's the part that freaked me out.  the "delete" phrase. haha.  I think it would of been better for the sharepoint developers to have said " this content type will be removed from the following library, rather than deleted..." thanks!

Comment: Ya, it freaked me out the first time I did it too

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate the library with another content type first. For example, Document. Make the new content type the "Default" and then you can remove the one that you do not want.