# Best Way to Remove Site Content Types from Lists

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, content-type

I am looking for the best way to remove content types from lists. I have 2 content types assigned to a list, but both of them share the same site columns.

I need suggestions on the best and easiest way to do this to avoid a lengthy mess.

I would like to just be able to clear the current content types from the list and start over with another content type.

Answer (score 0):

It should just be a matter of clicking on the Content Type in the library settings and clicking the delete this content type link. It won't delete it from the site collection, but will remove it from the library

[SharePoint 2013 - How to remove content type from library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133995/sharepoint-2013-how-to-remove-content-type-from-library)

**Update:**

1. Delete from site recycle bin.
2. Delete from Site Collection > Site Settings > Site Collection
   Administration > Recycle Bin.
3. Delete from  End User Recycle Bin Items.
4. Delete from "Deleted From End User Recycle Bin."

**Before deleting the Content Types from the site, you will need to delete them from all the lists in which these 2 content types are used. SharePoint won't allow deleting content types while in use in lists/libraries.**

Comment: -I was able to do that with one of my lists, but the others give me an error that says the "Content is still in use". I've deleted all the columns in the content type except the Task Name and Related Items, simply because it won't allow me to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Before deleting the Content Types from the site, you will need to delete them from all the lists in which these 2 content types are used. SharePoint won't allow deleting content types while in use in lists/libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174034/find-usages-of-content-type) for a couple of easy ways to check content type usage in a site. I used it not so long ago when I wanted to get rid of some old content types